# Can't pass variable from controller to view in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter-3

I am having a problem trying to pass a variable from the controller to the view. I think I am doing a mistake somewhere, I can't find it since I am new to it.

My controller Method is :

```
    public function paymentdetail($order_code)
{
    $this->load->model('Payment_Model');
    $paymentDetail = $this->Payment_Model->getpaymentdetail($order_code);
    $orderDetail = $this->Payment_Model->getOrderDetail($order_code);
    //        echo print_r($paymentDetail);
    $datas['content'] = $this->load->view('payment/paymentDetail',
        array('paymentDetail' => $paymentDetail,
            'orderDetail' => $orderDetail), true);
    $this->load->view('layouts/main_template', $datas);
}
```

The following model function `getpaymentdetail()` returns an array (result_array()) and this is the one I am concerned about. If I can work this one out then I can also work with other model methods.

```
$this->Payment_Model->getpaymentdetail($order_code);
```

When I type `<?php echo $paymentDetail['column_name']; ?>` in view file(PaymentDetail.php) I get an error

> `Undefined index: column_name`

Why do I get this error?

Comment: The variable `$paymentDetail['column_name']` does not exist. We can't help you, because we don't know what `$this->Payment_Model->getpaymentdetail($order_code)` returns. It's apparently not what you expect though.

Comment: Thank you for your interest.  `$this->Payment_Model->getpaymentdetail($order_code)` returns an array like the function `result_array()`.  I get values from the controller to view if I use `echo print_r($paymentDetail);` . I get the full array with value. But $paymentDetail['column_name'] is giving error that probably means I am doing something wrong that I don't know.

Comment: Directly after you set `$paymentDetail`, put `die("<pre>".print_r($paymentDetail, true)."</pre>");`

Run your script again and update your question with what that variable contains.

Comment: Also, update your question to show _where_ you are using `$paymentDetail['column_name']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> model function getpaymentdetail() returns an array (result_array())

those arrays are normally structured like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 3120
            [column_name] => col1
         )
)
```

hence you cannot access column_name via `<?php echo $paymentDetail['column_name']; ?>` as this index doesn't exist in your array structure.

if you move one index deeper, then it will work: `<?php echo $paymentDetail[0]['column_name']; ?>`

Attention, if you expect more than 1 row to be returned, above will only access the first result (indexed 0) row! You'd need a foreach loop to get all results, see [Generating Query Results - result arrays](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html#result-arrays)